# Execute command and store everything to variable in bash

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr, exit-status

In bash script I'm developing I'm trying to execute command and capture in variable(s):

- stdout
- stderr
- status code

how to achieve that? The command is `tar`, if it is of any significance.

I tried the most standard approach:

```
TAROUTPUT=$(tar -cf arch.tar /path/to/dir)
```

Based on some work I did (I haven't actually produced `tar` failure) I get only **stdout** from this, stderr is not stored to variable. The perfect solution has `TAROUTPUT` (with both stdout&stderr) and `TARSTATUS` variables.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
TAROUTPUT=$(tar -cf arch.tar /path/to/dir 2>&1)
this_is_the_tar_exit_code=$?
```

Comment: Yes, working, thanks. Will accept answer in a minute

Comment: @HaukeLaging: This puts stdout and stderr together into TAROUTPUT. If I understood the OP correctly, he wants to collect stdout and stderr into different variables.

Comment: @user1934428 That's not how I understand "TAROUTPUT (**with both** stdout&stderr)"

Answer (score 3):

If you want to separate `stdout` from `stderr`:

```
craft@engine:~$ tar -cf arch.tar /path/to/dir 1>/tmp/tar_stdout 2>/tmp/tar_stderr; RETCODE=$( echo ${?} );
craft@engine:~$ stdout_var=$( cat /tmp/tar_stdout )
craft@engine:~$ stderr_var=$( cat /tmp/tar_stderr )
craft@engine:~$ echo -e "STDOUT : ${stdout_var}\nSTDERR : ${stderr_var}\nCommand Status: ${RETCODE}"
```

- 1>/tmp/tar_stdout : save the `stdout` output to a temp file.
- 2>/tmp/tar_stderr : save `stderr` output to a file.
- Return code of the command (exit status) is saved into the `${?}` variable.